# Quasar Vue 3 route.push() not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, quasar

When I try to route to another page in js I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: route.push is not a function
```

code snippit:

```
    import { useRoute } from "vue-router";
    const route = useRoute();

    function openApp() {
        route.push("/#/home");
    };
```

when I use anchor tag around a btn the routing works

```
<a href="/#/home">
    <q-btn class="q-ma-md" color="primary" icon="check" label="OK" />
</a>
```

Any Ideas, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between `useRoute` and `useRouter`

Try this:

```
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
const router = useRouter();
router.push("/#/home");
```